# SSL failure on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

Hey I got a couple of errors and I need help to fix them because I can't find a solution for that.

Why am I using an old af version of ubuntu?

- Because I need to build android 4 and the easiest way to get the right versions of the needed packages is to use an older version of ubuntu which is confirmed to work
  So please don't tell me to just upgrade to the latest ubuntu

**Some commands that don't work because of a failure with ssl**

- when trying to access any website with firefox it returns `ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap`
  BUT google searches are working fine

```
$ repo init --depth=1 -u http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b ics
Downloading Repo source from http://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
fatal: Cannot get http://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error unknown url type: https
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

a small information how I got repo to work but didn't break apt (apt uses python2 and repo needs python3)

- I aliased python as python3 so when I run python as user it refers to python3 but when I run python as root it refers to the python symlink (/usr/bin/python) which is python2

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 83, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (60, 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')
```

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/Python-3.10.1.tgz
--2021-12-25 21:43:11--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/Python-3.10.1.tgz
Resolving www.python.org... 2a04:4e42:3::223, 151.101.12.223
Connecting to www.python.org|2a04:4e42:3::223|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

```
$ curl -v https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/Python-3.10.1.tgz
* About to connect() to www.python.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2a04:4e42:3::223... connected
* Connected to www.python.org (2a04:4e42:3::223) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

**Solutions I found online and tried but didn't work**

- checked if time is correct
- `update-ca-certificates -f`

Tell me if you need further information/logs or anything else
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not (yet) the certificates, it fails before validating these. Instead the versions of the SSL libraries used a simply too old. This means your software stack is way to old for today's requirements. There is no easy way to fix this.

In detail:
The openssl version in 11.10  is 0.9.8 which has no support for modern protocols like TLS 1.2 or even TLS 1.3. Similar the version of Firefox at the time of Ubuntu 11.10 did not support TLS 1.2 either (even though NSS and not openssl was used as SSL library).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Let's say I updated my openssl verion (compiled from source) to
`OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)`<br/>
But it still returns the same errors as before

As I said I literally can't move to a newer stack so do you know what else I would have to update to get the system running?

Comment: I tried recompiling wget from source since that could maybe fix the issue but it failes with the following error (sorry for posting a link, the error was just too long for a comment)
https://paste-bin.xyz/27620

Comment: @keine_Ide: Compile errors are a different question. But for me it looks like that you are not linking against the same version of OpenSSL as your were compiling against.  Note that you cannot simply replace the OpenSSL version on the system, but that you need to recompile and properly link everything (wget, Python, ...) against the new version. And for Firefox this means building Firefox and its TLS library NSS from source too. I very much doubt that 11.10 will still be an attractive option to use when all of these changes are involved.

Comment: I will try as you told me and at least recompile python3 since this is what I need working for the repo tool
Thanks for your patience :D